# Copy Pasting a folder using powershell, but with the regular file explorer GUI popup showing progress?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-explorer

Is it possible to automate, using powershell, the copying of a folder to a specified destination, BUT instead of using robocopy or copy-item, where there is no GUI progress popup, it somehow emulates a normal copy in file explorer and brings up a progress window as below?

[file explorer copy window pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qLGH.png)

Why?: I simply prefer file explorer's GUI. The ETA, the graph and the prettiness compared to any kind of powershell progress bar. This will be a user-facing script, so I want it to be less of an intimidating CLI experience.

Just wondering if this was possible, as it would be prettier and more familiar in terms of UX.

Comment: First question, why? Second, have you looked into PowerShell's built in progress window functions, write-progress?

Comment: I simply prefer file explorer's GUI. The ETA, the graph and the prettiness compared to any kind of powershell progress bar. This will be a user-facing script, so I want it to be less of an intimidating CLI experience.

Just wondering if this was possible, as it would be prettier and more familiar in terms of UX.

Comment: I also tried Copy-WithProgress, created by Trevor Sullivan here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883404/custom-robocopy-progress-bar-in-powershell

While it's a great tool ^ I'm simply questioning whether windows' pre-existing and polished copier can be powershell'd

Comment: Windows doesn't copy files or file folders. It copies FolderItem Objects to folder objects. These may or may not be files. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. I may be in need of some handholding for that link though as I only know powershell and know nothing of JS/VBS/VB

Comment: YES, thanks!!
You pointed me in the right direction with the copyhere method, then
I found the best powershell example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483865/copyhere-method/56484322

Comment: @Tom One thing I vaguely recall doing in the past is first running a `get-childitem` with applicable parameters, etc. and then save that to a variable. I then get the file object count from that variable and save to another variable to get total number of files to be copied. I then create a counter for each file copy operation and display that with detail so you get output per file copy operation of for example `Copied 1 of 25000`, `Copied 2 of 25000`, ..., ..., `Copied 24999 of 25000` and so on. I'm sure there is a trivial way to us similar logic you can plug in an equation to figure out a %.

Comment: I'll be happy to dig up a script from one of my toolboxes out there and provide you better example if you are interested but you will have to tag me back by name with `@PillsburyITDoughboy` and let me know @Tom. Otherwise maybe this will spark an idea for someone else that has something to post equilevant or better. Output to GUI with PS is only a trivial matter too. Get the output requirements that are satisfying first and then put into a GUI, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link given above in the comments, the powershell commands to copy using the standard windows shell copy should look like this

```
$source = "PATH:\TO\SOURCE"
$dest = "PATH:\TO\DESTFOLDER"

$objShell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$objFolder = $objShell.NameSpace($dest) 
$objFolder.CopyHere($source)
```

You can refer to the link in the comment to review the options you can pass to the CopyHere function. For example, to copy files with automatic "Yes to All", you would pass it like so

```
$objFolder.CopyHere($source, 16)
```